# Ruby on Rails 3.1 & Datatables gem 'simpe_datatables' (datatables.net)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, datatables

Does anybody have experience with datatables and Rails 3.1!?
I tried the simple_datatables 0.2.1 gem from :

https://github.com/gryphon/simple_datatables

with kaminari and meta_search 1.1.0 but could not make it working.

The table show up without images/css probably due to not properly
loaded css styles. Searching in the tables crashes also.... due to 
some weird search flags it passes to the backend. Example :
I have columns 'name' and 'size' and it passes : 'search[name_or_sizefalse]'
The backend does not like that.....and screams 'Unknown method' 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to checkout Ryan's railscast on datatables. I think he does a good job explaining and has an example to download. He is using will_paginate, but it should solve the issues you are having with kaminari.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables?autoplay=true

Good Luck!